# How can I trigger a codepipeline from codebuild not from commit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, aws-codepipeline

I am using bitbucket as source control and codepipeline as CI/CD tool. I created the codepipeline's source action from CDK as below code:

```
new actions.BitBucketSourceAction({
          actionName: 'SourceAction',
          owner: bitbucketOwner,
          connectionArn: codeStar,
          branch: branchName,
          output: this.sourceOutput,
          repo: bitbucketName,
        }),
```

after finish deploying codepipeline, it is triggered automatically when a commit pushed to bitbucket branch. How can I stop it doing that? I'd like to make a commit to trigger a codebuild project from where it triggers codepipeline.

In codepipeline source action console, I can see this checkbox:

[image]

but how can I set this configuration in CDK?

Answer (score 0):

**This has become possible** in version [1.95.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/releases/tag/v1.95.0). There is now [triggerOnPush](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-codepipeline-actions.BitBucketSourceActionProps.html#triggeronpushspan-classapi-icon-api-icon-experimental-titlethis-api-element-is-experimental-it-may-change-without-noticespan) parameter available in BitBucketSourceActionProps. Add it to your BitBucketSourceAction with value *false*

```
new actions.BitBucketSourceAction({
      actionName: 'SourceAction',
      owner: bitbucketOwner,
      connectionArn: codeStar,
      branch: branchName,
      output: this.sourceOutput,
      repo: bitbucketName,
      triggerOnPush: false
    }),
```

---

**Fun fact**: if someone needs Github version 2 source actions, BitBucketSourceAction works just fine also for github. It is just unfortunately named as admitted by CDK contributors [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/11582#issuecomment-730666842) and [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/10632#issuecomment-702293070). To avoid as much confussion as possible for my fellow developers I'm importing it using alias

```
import { BitBucketSourceAction as GitHubSourceAction } from "@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline-actions";

new GitHubSourceAction({
      actionName: 'SourceAction',
      owner: githubOwner,
      connectionArn: codeStar,
      branch: branchName,
      output: this.sourceOutput,
      repo: githubRepositoryName,
      triggerOnPush: false
    }),
```